# How to send a request with query parameters in gin

Tags: rest, go, routes, go-gin

I am trying to create a route for GET request with the username parameter. After sending the request from postman as localhost:9090/user/?username=abc I am unable to get the response. It is showing 404 error.

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/user", controllers.CreateUser)
    router.GET("/user/:username", GetUser)
    router.HEAD("/user/:username", controllers.GetUserMeta)

    router.Run("localhost:9090")
}

func GetUser(context *gin.Context) {
    // get specific record from database
    uname := context.Param("username")
    fmt.Println("received:", uname)
    //context.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, user)
}
```

I am wondering why the GetUser method is not executed.

Comment: That's because your route for `/user` only accepts POST. And your `GetUser` fundtion is bound to `/user/:username`, not `/user`, which you're calling.

Comment: Thanks Flimzy. Does this mean, I need to do `router.GET("/:username", GetUser)` ?

Comment: It means you need your request to match your route.  You can do that by changing the request, or by changing the route. If you want to change your request, try `/user/abc`. If you want to change your route, use `router.GET("/user", GetUser)`, then have GetUser read the query paramter.

Comment: Got it. It works now. I changed my request. Thanks a lot for your response!!